# Terminology to use for dependencies

Tags: mysql, database-design, graph, dependencies, naming-conventions

What is the accepted terminology to use for referring to the items of a dependency?

I've been using `parent` and `child`, where parents depend on their children, but this caused some confusion when someone else thought that children depended on their parents. Arguably both are true in real life.

We found that `dependent` isn't clear enough- you have to think really hard about which end it is referring to.

Bonus points for links to documents using or better yet discussing such terminology.

Comment: I've only ever heard of a child being the dependent. That goes for real life too.

Comment: @bmewsing That should be an (the) answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end we decided to use `item` and `depends_on`. It's easy to read and avoids any ambiguity.

You could use `dependent` and `depends_on`, but it doesn't read as well.

Someone suggested `requires` and `enables` - I really like this.

Comment: I'm also kinda stuck on the naming here... to clearify I need a proper term for the `items` that depend on/require a specific `item`, let's say the opposite of its own dependencies/requirements. What i came up with so far..  
  
`??? <- item -> dependencies`  
`upstream <- item -> downstream`
`enables <- item -> requires`

I like the last one too, but i like the 1st one better :) however im  not sure what (semantically-wise) the right opposite term would be.. any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

I've only ever heard of a child being the dependent. That goes for real life too (excluding some scenarios involving sickness or old age). From modelling heirachies in a database to filling out my tax return at the end of the year to changing nappies(diapers), my experience has been that a child always is the dependent of a parent.

If you need to describe entity relationships more thoroughly then you can use [ER modelling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model). Or on the attribute level [functional dependencies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_dependency).

Answer (score 0):

"Parent" and "child" are fine.

At the level of physical FOREIGN KEYs, the terms "referencing" and "referenced" are sometime used.

When talking about X:Y relationships in the logical model, the cardinality is sometimes used. For example, a 1:N relationship might use the terms: "1 endpoint" and "N endpoint".